# Optimize SQL query by grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table with the following structure

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| make        | varchar(55)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model       | varchar(55)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| year        | varchar(4)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and some sample data

```
('Chevrolet', 'Express', '2001'),
('Chevrolet', 'Express', '2002'),
('Chevrolet', 'Venture', '2001'),
('Chevrolet', 'Venture', '2002'),
('Dodge', 'Dakota', '2000'),
('Dodge', 'Dakota', '2001'),
('Ford', 'Flex', '2009'),
('Ford', 'Flex', '2010'),
```

What I want is one fast query that can return me all the models, with all the makes and years attached. So the following is an example of something I would like returned.

```
Array
(
    [Chevrolet] => Array
        (
            [Express] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2001
                    [1] => 2002
                )

            [Venture] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2001
                    [1] => 2002
                )
        )

    [Dodge] => Array
        (
            [Dakota] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2001
                    [1] => 2002
                )
        )

    [Ford] => Array
        (
            [Flex] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2009
                    [1] => 2010
                )
        )
)
```

**What I am currently doing:**

I have one query to return all the unique makes:

```
$sql = "select distinct make from listings order by make asc ";
```

and once I have every make, I loop through and run the following query, using the make:

```
$sql = "select distinct model from listings where make = ? order by model asc ";
```

and I go one more step to grab the years:

```
$sql = "select distinct year from listings where make=? and model=? order by year desc";
```

Comment: Share us the explain plan of the query, and the indexes on the tables...

Comment: @SashiKant I do not currently have any indexes on the table, and the explain outputs the same as the describe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT make, model, year
FROM listings
ORDER BY make, model, year
```